# iptables FORWARD all connections from a client through a gateway to a server

Tags: iptables

I would like to forward all ports from my client (windows) to a server (windows) that is behind a Gateway (linux).

My network topology look as following:

```
10.20.10.14 --> 10.20.10.4 --> 192.168.1.1 --> 192.168.1.4
   client          ppp0           eth0          server
                |--------- Gateway -------|
```

where the Gateway device have two network devices: ppp0 and eth0.

I would like that in case of a network connection between client to ppp0, the server device will see the data on the same port as it was sent from the client.

In other words, the server should think, that it communicate directly with the client and the Gateways is transperent in this case.

In addition I would like to know how to remove this rule.

Any ideas?

Remark:
I am the admin on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating English rules into iptables rules, only this rule is needed:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.20.10.14 -i ppp0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4
```

Destination port is not altered (and source port shouln't be either except rare cases when the client simultaneously connects directly to the server).

Nothing prevents the client to manually add a route to `192.168.1.4` via `10.20.10.4` and access directly the server. If you don't want this, to keep the server's IP hidden, you can also add this rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.20.10.14 -i ppp0 -d 192.168.1.4 -m conntrack ! --ctstate DNAT -j DROP
```

This will drop a direct access to the server that wasn't DNATed.

To remove those rules, simply use `-D`:

```
iptables -D FORWARD -s 10.20.10.14 -i ppp0 -d 192.168.1.4 -m conntrack ! --ctstate DNAT -j DROP
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -s 10.20.10.14 -i ppp0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4
```

---

Random remarks:

- IP forwarding must be enabled on the Gateway since the DNATed connection is forwarded. The easiest to do this would be `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.
- the server needs of course a route to the client to accept its connections, eg having Gateway (`192.168.1.1`) as default gateway.
- `-i ppp0` is optional and can be removed (or replaced with `-d 10.20.10.4` in the PREROUTING rule if preferred). It can cause problems if not replaced with `-i ppp+` (`+` being a wildcard): when there's a rapid link failure/reconnection, the new ppp interface might be called `ppp1` if `ppp0` wasn't torn off before. The iptables rules wouldn't match anymore.
- already established flows won't be affected when the DNAT rule is removed, newer flows will be (ie won't reach server).

Comment: I believe, that in addition i will need 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'. Am i currect?

Comment: Indeed. I'll add it in the random remarks, since it's already assumed Gateway is a router